# Reading/writing files outside DocumentRoot with apache and perl

Tags: apache, perl

I have a perl cgi script that was written by someone else and I'm trying to maintain without really understanding it. The following piece of code from a script that's run from apache is supposed to read a string from a file and it fails with a permission denied error.

This is on a fedora20 system with perl-5.18.4 and apache-2.4.10.

The `$changepass_dir` value is `/var/changepass_temp` and it is owned by `apache.apache`. If I `su` to the `apache` user, I can read the `$value{'username'}.fail` file in `/var/changepass_temp` just fine.

However, it prints `OOPs /var/changepass_temp user1 -- Permission denied` when run directly from apache.

```
if(-e "$changepass_dir/$value{'username'}\.fail"){

                    &login_fail($value{'username'},$value{'ip'});
                    open(IN,"$changepass_dir/$value{'username'}\.fail") || print ("OOPs $changepass_dir $value{'username'}  -- $!");
                    my $message = join('',<IN>);
                    unlink("$changepass_dir/$value{'username'}.fail");
                    &print_error($message);
                    last;
 }
```

The whole script is many hundreds of lines long, so I didn't think it was appropriate to post the whole thing. Hopefully there's enough here to determine why this is a problem?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I should also mention that selinux is disabled for now.

Comment: I should have also mentioned the error message that apache produces is:


`[Thu Jan 22 00:18:56.261500 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 569] [client 68.195.193.42:57097] AH01215: [Thu Jan 22 00:18:56 2015] changepass.cgi: readline() on closed filehandle IN at /var/www/mail.example.com-443/html/changepass.cgi line 395., referer: https://webstage.example.com/changepass.cgi`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I don't think the problem lies there. The reason you get that error in the log is because the `open` has failed - printing an error instead - but your script proceeds past and still tries to read data from a file it can't access. (That's probably not a good thing, because it then deletes the file without having processed it).

This will be permissions related.

Because your `-e` test works (file exists) that means you do have some permissions, and are looking in the right place. That means you can probably compare the access permissions of that directory and see if there's any differences.

My best guess based on what you've put so far is that your script *isn't* running as `apache`. It's not uncommon to drop privileges of scripts even further, to avoid exploit conditions.

Ways to test that - a simple `ps` might do the trick, but alternatively you could try adding:

```
open ( my $tmp_file, ">", '/tmp/test_file' ) or warn $!;
```

Check that a file is created, and who owns it.

Comment: I tried your open() test, and not only didn't it print an error, it didn't create the file. I'm confident it's executing specifically that block of code because I've created unique text to identify the other error message that's produced.

There is another process that creates the files that this process reads. Could it somehow be related to that? Perhaps some type of locking issue?

Comment: I added `touch /var/changepass_temp/myfile` (with the backticks) and it also failed to create the file or give any warning/error message. The directory has 777 permissions and owned by apache.

Is there some other apache setting that controls where and how the daemon can write to files?

Comment: That warn should give an error in your logs. But it's probably `permission denied` :)

Comment: If I can write to that file as that user, could there still be a permission denied issue? What would prevent it from being able to write to /tmp? Or /var/tmp?

Comment: Actually, there's a related problem on /var/tmp which may be applicable. https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/